# Snapping to the side of the screen in GNOME disables the resizing of the window

Tags: gnome

When I snap to the left or to the right edge of the screen, the window is no longer re-sizable. I didn't have this problem in Unity. Does anybody have a solution for this?

[image: Can't resize window when snapped to side of the screen.]
[image: It's possible to resize once the window has been moved out of the snapped position.]

### System Info

```
Ubuntu 17.04 (kernel information: Linux 4.10.0-37-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 20:20:37 UTC 2017)
GNOME Shell 3.24.2
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's an intended half-tiling feature (you may call it a bug if you wish) and it seems there's no workaround. GNOME v3.26 (the one to be shipped with Ubuntu 17.10) has a feature which resizes [both the half-maximised windows at the same time](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/smarter-window-snapping-coming-gnome-shell) just by resizing one or other. For advanced tiling options you may look for some extensions in https://extensions.gnome.org/, for example:
zTile, gTile, Tilingnome, shellshape, ShellTile etc.

Comment: @pomsky Even though that be the case, I can't see why it has stopped them from allowing the windows to still be resized; this seems naturally desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's an intended half-tiling feature (you may call it a bug if you wish) and it seems there's no workaround. There was an option to do it by <kbd>super</kbd>+*middle mouse button drag* in older versions of GNOME shell, but it seems it's been dropped.

According to a one [OMG! Ubuntu! article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/smarter-window-snapping-coming-gnome-shell), GNOME v3.26 (the one to be shipped with Ubuntu 17.10) has a feature which lets users tile windows to available width (not an arbitrary 50%) [see this [video demo](https://youtu.be/vfj5KjAm-LE?t=10s)] and resize both the half-maximised windows at the same time just by resizing one or other.

For advanced tiling options you may look for some extensions in [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/), for example:

- [zTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1298/ztile/)
- [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/)
- [Tilingnome](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1286/tilingnome/)
- [shellshape](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/294/shellshape/)
- [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)

etc.

---

#### Update from the original asker

I tried some of these extensions. *zTile*, *gTile* seem a bit buggy at the moment (at least with my current configuration). I tried *ShellTile* and can confirm that this does fix this "issue".

Comment: I tried some of these extensions. _zTile_, _gTile_ seem a bit buggy at the moment (at least with my [current configuration](https://askubuntu.com/q/964888/730176)). I tried _ShellTile_ and can confirm that this does fix this "issue". I can't see, by the way, how this could ever be an "intended" feature.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to GNOME 3.26. I think you will find that resizing works the way that you want. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/smarter-window-snapping-coming-gnome-shell

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Could you suggest a way to upgrade to GNOME 3.26 while using Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 without breaking stuffs?

Comment: @pomsky That's also been my main concern when looking into this.